# NamingException: Cannot create resource instance with Jackrabbit in Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, repository, jackrabbit

I have deployed Jackrabbit in Tomcat 7 using the model 2 ([Shared J2EE Resource](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/shared-j2ee-resource-howto.html)), but when I try to acces the repository I get the `NamingException` exception.

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
  at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:144)
  at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
```

My code is:

```java
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
Context environment = (Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env");

// The exception is thrown in this line
Repository repository = (Repository) environment.lookup("jcr/repository");
```

I added this resource as a `GlobalNamingResource` in my Tomcat `server.xml`:

```xml
<Resource name="jcr/globalRepository"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.jcr.Repository"
    factory="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepositoryFactory"
    configFilePath="C:\Users\vgomez\repository.xml"
    repHomeDir="C:\Users\vgomez\repository"/>
```

In `context.xml` I added the `ResourceLink`:

```xml
<ResourceLink 
    name="jcr/repository"
    global="jcr/globalRepository"
    type="javax.jcr.Repository"/>
```

And the `web.xml` of my web app is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" 
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>JCR Repository</description>
        <res-ref-name>jcr/repository</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.jcr.Repository</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
     </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

Edit: This problem appears when the web app uses Vaadin. If the web app uses jsf for example this configuration works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I think I didn't have all the dependencies needed. For a Vaadin project created using the comand given in the [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/getting-started.maven.html) this is the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>jackrabbitVaadin</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>jackrabbitVaadin</name>

<properties>
    <vaadin.version>7.5.9</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <jetty.plugin.version>9.2.3.v20140905</jetty.plugin.version>
    <project.source.version>1.7</project.source.version>
    <project.target.version>1.7</project.target.version>
    <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackrabbit-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <scope></scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-rmi</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackrabbit-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Needed when using the widgetset optimizer (custom ConnectorBundleLoaderFactory). 
        For widgetset compilation, vaadin-client-compiler is automatically added 
        on the compilation classpath by vaadin-maven-plugin so normally there is 
        no need for an explicit dependency. -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId> <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId> 
        <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
                <source>${project.source.version}</source>
                <target>${project.target.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <!-- Exclude some unnecessary files generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache/**,
                    WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                <style>OBF</style>
                <strict>true</strict>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!-- disabled by default to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                        <!-- <goal>compile-theme</goal> -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/styles.css</include>
                            <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by 
            running jetty:run on the command line. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <!-- TODO Remove when http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/14924 is resolved -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        vaadin-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[7.1.11,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources</goal>
                                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>
```